# In Excel, give a function to give column header value based on column values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have data like this

| Value | apples | oranges | bananas |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | TRUE | FALSE | FALSE |
|  | FALSE | TRUE | FALSE |

I need a function that gives the header of the column that contains "TRUE". So for the first row in the value column it would give "apples" and in the second row "oranges". I tried all sorts of combinations of MATCH and INDEX functions but couldn't make it work.

Answer (score 3):

Try using the following formula which uses `REPT()` & `CONCAT()`:

[image]

---

```
=CONCAT(REPT(B$1:D$1,B2:D2))
```

---

Or, Using `TOROW()` & `IFS()`

```
=TOROW(IFS(B2:D2,B$1:D$1),2)
```

---

But, if there are multiple `TRUE` then:

```
=TEXTJOIN("|",,TOROW(IFS(B2:D2,B$1:D$1),2))
```

---

Or,

```
=TEXTJOIN("|",,REPT(B$1:D$1,B2:D2))
```

---

Also, a nice suggestion by **[JvdV](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9758194/jvdv)** Sir, if single `TRUE` per row then:

[image]

---

```
=TOCOL(IFS(B2:D3,B1:D1),2)
```

---

Or As suggested by **[DS_London](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13812982/ds-london)** Sir.

```
=FILTER($B$1:$D$1,B2:D2)
```

---

Or, A single formula for the grid if more than one TRUE.

```
=BYROW(B2:D3,LAMBDA(r,TEXTJOIN(",",,IF(r,B1:D1,""))))
```

---

Comment: `=TOCOL(IFS(B2:D3,B1:D1),2)` perhaps to do it in a single go, assuming a single `TRUE` per row.

Comment: Sir yes agree updated now!

Comment: Or `=FILTER($B$1:$D$1,B2:D2)` for a single row with one `TRUE`. Or `=BYROW(B2:D3,LAMBDA(r,TEXTJOIN(",",,FILTER(B1:D1,r))))` as a single formula for the grid if more than one TRUE.

Comment: @DS_London Sir, yes `FILTER()` works as well!

Comment: or indeed `=BYROW(B2:D3,LAMBDA(r,TEXTJOIN(",",,IF(r,B1:D1,""))))` ...

Comment: @DS_London Sir, may I update your solutions in the answers?

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya Of course, it you think it would be useful.

Comment: All done added.